# Cooperative Enzyme Question

Tags: biochemistry, homework, enzymes

I'm currently studying for the MCATs. After doing some biochemistry practice questions, I came upon a question that I believe may be incorrectly posed. I was wondering if I'm correct in saying this or not.

The question is: " A certain cooperative enzyme has four subunits, two of which are bound to substrate. Which of the following statements can be made?"

The correct answer is "The affinity of the enzyme for the substrate is greater than with one substrate bound."

My confusion lies in the fact that the question never specified whether this cooperative enzyme had a positive or negative Hill coefficient. When approaching future questions like this, should I assume a positive Hill coefficient?

Comment: You need to rephrase your question. This list cannot give advice on interpreting examination questions, or whether questions are ambiguous. Only questions about biology are valid. We can answer questions about the binding of substrates to enzymes showing positive or negative cooperativity or whether such enzymes exist. These might be a way of establishing whether or not you are correct. Then you can draw your own conclusions about the academic level at which the question is pitched and your best examination strategy.